# Programmatically Set the android query in manifest for declaring package names

Tags: android, manifest, android-11

I have two APPS and I am using each other's data(using content provider) and declaring package name in manifest file under query tag, it is working fine,

But I want to declare query and package name programmatically,

How can achieve this

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "declare query and package name programmatically"? Do you mean that you want to change the values at runtime? If so, that is not an option AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, I am want
 
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Above one to set programmatically if possible, i have researched on this but could not got answers yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"?

Comment: I want to achieve it in my Kotlin class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot change the package visibility rules at runtime from Java/Kotlin.

Comment: could you share any relevant link or resource on this.

Comment: @AkashMeena: The [documentation on package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) offers no options for changing the rules at runtime.